# Waiting for a background thread to complete before function return

Tags: swift, function, reachability, background-thread

I try to create function that return Internet status as `Bool`:

```
func isConnectedToNetwork()->Bool{
    var InternetStatus = Bool()
    RealReachability.sharedInstance().reachabilityWithBlock { (status:ReachabilityStatus) in
        switch status {
        case .RealStatusNotReachable:
            InternetStatus = false
        default:
            InternetStatus = true

        }
    }
   return InternetStatus
}
```

But I have a problem, `RealReachability.sharedInstance().reachabilityWithBlock {}` works in background thread, and function return before background thread complete.

How to wait background thread result before function return?

Comment: You can't. This must be the most commonly asked iOS question. Please search on Stack Overflow before asking. Search for _asynchronous_. See, for example, my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24520296/341994

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been asked and answered many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: matt, you're wrong! I can to do this using semaphores! Please don't voting to close this questions.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you should not. So don't. Don't. Listen to what you're being told (by me, by vadian, by all the answers about this topic on Stack Overflow). Semaphores block the main thread while the network is accessed, for however long it takes. This will hang up your app's interface and may even cause the WatchDog process to kill you app stone dead on the spot. And even if the hang-up is short, it's still wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't wait, tell.

Use a completion handler which is called when the asynchronous task has been completed

```
func isConnectedToNetwork(completion:(Bool -> Void)) {
    RealReachability.sharedInstance().reachabilityWithBlock { (status:ReachabilityStatus) in
        switch status {
        case .RealStatusNotReachable:
            completion(false)
        default:
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

and call it

```
isConnectedToNetwork { success in
  print(success)
  // do something with the success value
}
```

Comment: vadian, no need to use completion handler... Just need to use semaphores...! But thank you for answer!

Comment: @Dmitry semaphores are pretty bad programming habit In this case.

Comment: So does the completion handler and is much more efficient.