# ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion not working in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, ios7.1

[ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion iOS 7 and semaphores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966283/abaddressbookrequestaccesswithcompletion-ios-7-and-semaphores)

I have checked above link for asking a permission for address book in IOS 7 device but it's not working.
Here we are using "ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion" method to ask a permission,it's works perfectly in all IOS 7 simulators but while we are testing it in ios 7 device (iPhone 4,4s,5c) it will not ask for the permission to user but app already has to permission for same.

to confirm this issues i follow some steps when i install the app in simulator and before i run the code in above link it will not shows my application in setting>privacy.But meanwhile in device it show my application in device and also permission is granted.

So kindly help me out for sort out this issues.

I'm using Xcode 5.1.1, simulator with os ios 7.1(ratina 3.4,4.0 and 4.0 64 bit),and device 4,4s and 5c with ios 7.1.

Comment: Does this happen on all devices or just a specific device? Is it possible you have some app already installed on the device with access to addressbook allowed which uses same bundle identifier as your app is using?

Comment: it's happening in all the device i mention as well as other 3 5c Device of my friend.and i checked bundle identifier it's a different from all other application.

Comment: I see you are following code in question which does not have answer. That code may not be working..Follow this Apple sample code:[QuickContacts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475) and try to figure out the issue in your code. If you still face problems please post relevant code in your question.

Comment: One more thing when ever i install application in device it get permission for access contact by default.I checked it when i install the app and before running this code in setting it shows my app with access permission allowed.And it's quiet shocking this is happening with another two application i develop and use same code.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because there's another app on your hardware devices that uses the same bundle ID of your app. Try to check it.